# Taking a substring of a ByteString in Akka/Scala

Tags: scala, akka

I'm using Akka to develop a server application and I was wondering if there was a "cleaner" way to go about getting a substring of a `ByteString` - Something like

```
bytestr.getSubstringAtFor(int start, int len): ByteString
```

or similar. Right now I'm converting the `ByteString` to a list, creating another `List[Byte]`, looping over it with a for loop and copying the relevant bytes to my new list, then converting that list of bytes back to a `ByteString`.

Is there a "cleaner" way to get a substring of a ByteString?

Comment: I may have reduced my code somewhat - I'm now using `bytestr.drop(start).copyToArray(byteArray, 0, len)` then converting the byte array to a ByteString.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `slice` to get a contiguous subset of the bytes taking a start index that is inclusive and an end index that is exclusive.   For instance, if you had a `ByteString` wrapping the string "foobar" and wanted to get a `ByteString` of just "oob" then that would look like this:

```
val bs = ByteString("foobar")
val subbs = bs.slice(1, 4)
```